# htaccess redirect based on cookies

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cookie

I need a welcome page for new visits. If a user don0t have the cookie stored, he will be redirected to welcome page. If the cookie is stored, nothing happens.

`Header set Set-Cookie "visited=true"

RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^visited=true$ [NC]

RewriteRule .? /welcome.html [R=301,NC,L]`

Cookie is working, but all users are being redirected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order...you're setting the cookie before the engine. Move the `Header` line below your rewrite rule and it should work.

Comment: It still doesn't work. All users get redirected on welcome page